# Using Foreign Keys in Django Template w/django-simple-history

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-simple-history

I'm trying to display values associated with a foreign key while rendering a Django Template.  I've emulated other answers on this site to no avail.

I'm using the package django-simple-history to track changes to all the records in my database's primary table. This table has a foreign key named history_user_id which corresponds to the id in the django table auth_user.

According to this example ([Display foreign key value in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285061/display-foreign-key-value-in-django-template)) I should be able to display the usernames of users who have amended the database by using the following code:

```
<ul>{% for item in history %}
     <li>{{item.history_user_id.username}}</li>
</ul>{% endfor %}
```

where history is defined in my views.py as

```
def view_history(request,pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    history = project.history.all()
    return render(
        request,
        "projects/view_history.html",
        {
            "project": project,
            "history": history,
        }
    )
```

The template I create can interpret item.history_user_id, and I can manually look into the table auth_user to the corresponding username, but when I try to use the template to render the username I get a blank instead.  Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly `item.history_user_id` is the id of the user who did the change. This is an integer, which of course does not have any property called `user`. If a django template hits a non-existant variable it will just leave it blank (and not raise an error). Therefore you a seeing nothing in your template.

So change your code to get the user rather than the user_id

```
<ul>{% for item in history %}
     <li>{{item.history_user}}</li>
</ul>{% endfor %}
```

This is described in the [docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html).