# How can I upload multiple files in to a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload, django-model-field

I'm trying to make an LMS system with Django and now I need to upload multiple pdf files to the curriculum of the class. I can upload one file with the `OnetoOne` field in the Django model but not more. When I try to add another material for the same class it says `Upload materials with this Uploaded class already exists.` This is my model code.

```
class UploadMaterials(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uploaded_class = models.OneToOneField(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='upload_materials')
    upload_material = models.FileField(upload_to=rename, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Materials"
```

I need to upload the materials and be able to view them in the template. like......

```
{% for material in class.materials %}
<h1>{{ material.name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried the Django `ForeignKey` instead of `OnetoOne` and was able to create multiple materials for the same class
but could not figure out how to access them from the template.

What I want to know is how to upload multiple files to the same class and how to access them in the template.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try insert this pattern on your code:

```
file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

It's send multiple files upload.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: This was not the answer i wanted but thank you for trying. I found a answer here after a little search [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285061/display-foreign-key-value-in-django-template]