# Django | Queryset ManyToMany Relation through Instance

Tags: django

I would like to display the different dates for each course. A course can also have several dates. Unfortunately I can't find a solution.

Models:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_number = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    course_location = models.ForeignKey(Course_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_dates = models.ManyToManyField('Course_dates', through="Course_Course_dates")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_number

class Course_Course_dates(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_dates = models.ForeignKey(Course_dates, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Course_dates(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    trainer = models.ManyToManyField('Trainer', through="Course_dates_trainer")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

View:

```
def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    course_list = []

    for course in courses:
        course_location = course.course_location.description
        dates = course.course_dates.all()
        
        course_list.append({'course': course, 'course_location': course_location, 'dates': dates,})
    
    context = { 'course_list': course_list, }
    return render(request, 'kursverwaltung_tenant/course.html', context)
```

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Please explain what is not working.

Comment: I would  like to display the different dates for each course. But the template does not show any dates.

Here my Template:
`{% for object in course_list %}
<tr class="small">
<td><a href={{ object.id }}><i class='bx bx-edit' ></i></a></td>
<td>
{{ objects.dates }}
</td>
[...]`

Answer (score 1):

Your courses queryset will already have access to your course dates through the foreign key so you don't need to run a second dates queryset in the view to access them.

When you loop through the courses, you'll then need to run a second loop through the dates of those courses within your template. Here's an example of that:
[Display foreign key value in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285061/display-foreign-key-value-in-django-template)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I even had the right solution before. But I made a mistake in the template. ".all()" instead ".all"